# Reload page if error "IndexError: list index out of range" occures

Tags: javascript, jquery, python, events

I am scraping web pages and sometimes the age does not load correctly and the error occurs

> IndexError: list index out of range

This is because with the page not loading correctly it does not have the index. reloading the page solves this.

Is there away to add in error handling so if page is not loaded and the error occurs... reload the page?

I have searched the internet and cannot find anything

```
for link in links:

    #print('Fetching from link: ' + link)
    browser.get('http://www.racingpost.com' + link)
    time.sleep(5)
    print('http://www.racingpost.com' + link) 
    tree = html.fromstring(browser.page_source)
    #print(browser.page_source)
    if count == 0:
        browser.find_element_by_xpath("//*[@id='re_']/div[2]/a[1]").click()
        browser.find_element_by_xpath("//*[@id='re_']/div[2]/a[2]").click()
        count = count + 1

    #first of all pull all the data about the event its self like going distance ect
    title = tree.xpath('//*[@id="mainwrapper"]/div/div/div[2]/div[1]/div[2]/h3/text()[2]')
    title = map(lambda x:x.strip(),title)
    title = [x.strip(' ') for x in title]
    details = tree.xpath('//*[@id="mainwrapper"]/div/div/div[2]/div[1]/div[2]/ul/li[1]/text()[1]')
    prizemoney = tree.xpath('//*[@id="mainwrapper"]/div/div/div[2]/div[1]/div[2]/ul/li[2]/text()[1]')
    setoff = tree.xpath('//*[@id="mainwrapper"]/div/div/div[2]/div[1]/div[2]/h3/span/text()')
    course = tree.xpath('//*[@id="mainwrapper"]/div/div/div[2]/div[1]/div[2]/h1/text()[1]')
    print(course)
    course[0] = course[0].replace('Result', '')
    date = tree.xpath('//*[@id="mainwrapper"]/div/div/div[2]/div[1]/div[2]/h1/text()[2]')
    timeoff = tree.xpath('//div[@class="raceInfo"]/text()[3]')
```

above is a code snippit -> if borwser.get does not grab page (server rejects or timeout) then id need to retry.

Comment: What are using `scrapy`? If yes then it will try the same page thrice or otherwise you can check its documentation for the same.

Comment: im using lxml -xpath (added to the description - first time posting here :) )

Comment: Without any code it's hard to answer. But usually you need a place to catch this Error and make re-try request.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you need to make a little refactoring. 
It should be something like this:

```
def get_page(link):
   # all code stuff for fetching page
   # this code could return ether error code or throw Exception
   return data

for link in links:
  try:
     result = get_page(link)
     # here you need to add this result 
  except IndexError:
     #log this error
     result = get_page(link) #this is retry. you can add slip() here too
```

This is quick and dirty example, you can improve it with better retries logging, counting retries for each link globally and so on.

Answer (score 1):

You can add a try/exception error which will return some kind of variable to tell the page that it has not loaded properly then you can use javascript function `location.reload()` to reload the page.

For example:
In your Python Script:

```
try:
    'Your Code Goes Here'
except IndexError:
     return 'e'
```

And in your Javascript:

```
if(xml.responsetext=='e'){
    location.reload(true);//true if you dont want to load from cache,otherwise leave it blank
    }
```

Report me if there is any error , as I am also trying to use python script with AJAX in my website and I am quite new to it.I would have loved to comment instead of answering it but my reputation doesnt allow me to do so.

Cheers